# UWP - C# - How to simulate a SugestionChosen in AutosSearchBox programattically?

Tags: c#, uwp, barcode

I use an Auto Search Box in order to look for products. I can search by name or by ID. Now, I want to add a barcode scanner to speed up invoice registration. After obtaining barcode, I get the product but I don't know how to get the SugestionChosen event in order to get the SelectedItem in ItemsSource. Usually this happens when user selects an option in the AutoSearchBox list. Do you know how to solve this requirement?

```
    private void ProductSearchBox_TextChanged(AutoSuggestBox sender, 
             AutoSuggestBoxTextChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        if (args.Reason == AutoSuggestionBoxTextChangeReason.UserInput)
        {
            // here look for products
            ViewModel.SearchingProducto(sender.Text);
            sender.ItemsSource = ViewModel.ProductSuggestions;

            // if there is only one coincidence and length match with lenght 
            // barcode
            if (ViewModel.ProductSuggestions.Count == 1 & 
                ProductSearchBox.Text.Length == 13)
            {

              //
              //   Here I want to simulate SugestionChosen event in order to 
              //    get the product which barcode matchs
              //

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: just call the event after you scan te code? if you want more help share relevant code.

Comment: Do you mean when you get the product(e.g. productName) by barcode,you want to get the product model corresponding to the product name?If yes,you can get the product model by `ViewModel.SearchingProducto(productName);` and `var model = ViewModel.ProductSuggestions[0];`.ProductSuggestions will only have one product by barcode scanning, so the first element is the model you scanned.If not, can you describe the scenario in more detail?

Comment: @Faywang Effectevely I've taken that approach and it works fine! Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

As @Faywang said, "you can get the product model by ViewModel.SearchingProducto(productName); and var model = ViewModel.ProductSuggestions[0];.ProductSuggestions will only have one product by barcode scanning, so the first element is the model you scanned"